# How to add a single file from one git repository to another?

Tags: git, version-control, content-based-retrieval

Is it possible to add a single-file resource from one Git repo to another?

Kind of like of like submodules but even more lightweight

```
git import repo:file:SHA1
```

Until Internet itself gets builtin content based addressing, I see no reason to not provide such a feature in Git.

Comment: See http://gbayer.com/development/moving-files-from-one-git-repository-to-another-preserving-history/

Comment: Do you want to keep being able to update that single file in another repository? Then you will have to use a submodule—even for a single file (Git repositories are already extremely lightweight, so don’t worry about that). Otherwise, if you just want to have the file in the repository, copy and paste it there.